# UITableViewCell give Padding both side

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview

Hi in my iPhone app i created custom UITableViewCell as a separate nib file now i need to give the space both left and right side space for show scrollbar(indicator like twitter app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should already be the case. If you have set your `UITableView` to "**Grouped**", then this is what you will see and there are no other options to configure.